# How to implement 2 way character streams

Tags: java

How can we implement a 2-way character stream? Say for example:

> an

is inserted in the character stream, but user wants to insert another character at beginning of above stream:

> man

So here `m` is inserted at beginning. Then user wants to add another to end:

> mano

Also as soon as characters are inserted in stream, it needs to be processed by system, so for example `an` will be processed first, followed by `man` and then `mano`.

**NOTE:** Let me know if anyother post seems appropriate for this, or if its a duplicate somehow.

Comment: [`LindedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a start, well [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) to be more general

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the interface [`Deque<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) that provide:

> A linear collection that supports element insertion and removal at both ends.

That collection provide

- [`addFirst(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addFirst(E))
- [`addLast(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addLast(E))

Comment: Thanks @AxelH, my bad it didn't hit me at beginning and missed out deque, and costed me multiple downvotes, lolz. Thanks for help. :) cheers

Comment: sorry I do not see how Deque is related to a two way character stream. I understand how a Dequeue may be used to insert element at start of a list, but stream reading is aimed at reading files of any size I I do not think that this answer match the question.